# create multiple events android map application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-maps

i'm creating a map app that displays events with a description overlay that pops up on click.
i've currently used 2 tutorials
[tutorial 1)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html)
[tutorial 22)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html)
currently i can display 1 event by defiining the long+lat,

my question is how do i add several events?
also how can i add events from a csv file which contains the long+lat and description for the event?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is how do i add several events?

Put multiple `OverlayItems` in the `ItemizedOverlay`.

> also how can i add events from a csv file which contains the long+lat and description for the event?

Use Java I/O to read in the file.